# .npmrc - env vars not expanded?

Tags: node.js

I need to easily install packages based on some predefined variables.

So i set

```
export NPMDIR=dev
```

or

```
export NPMDIR=prod
```

then in `.npmrc`

```
prefix=/usr/local/npm/$NPMDIR
```

and all packages are installed in `/usr/local/npm/$NPMDIR` literally instead 
of `/usr/local/npm/dev`, `/usr/local/npm/prod` etc.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely you need brackets around your variables:

```
prefix=/usr/local/npm/${NPMDIR}
```