# .npmrc not expanding env variable

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I am setting an environment variable and then attempting to use it in a .npmrc file during `npm install`, but the token variable appears to be unavailable.

Here's my script (config.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN=$(firebase functions:config:get npm.read_only)

export NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN=$(eval echo $NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN)

# exit 0;
```

Here's my package.json preinstall script:

```
"preinstall: ". ./config.sh && echo $NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN"
```

And my .npmrc:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN
```

When I run `npm install`, the preinstall script executes and the correct token prints, but then during the install I get:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @scoped/package@1.x
```

I'm beginning to think that the token is not actually available to the .npmrc file. To test this, I echoed the token in a postinstall script and it did not print the token. Note that I tested with without the scoped package as a dependency so that the postinstall script would be reached. I also verified that my package was available by plugging the token directly into .npmrc and it downloaded successfully.

I dug around quite a bit and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534412/npmrc-env-vars-not-expanded) post. Adding curly braces around the variable name in the .npmrc file does not fix it and in fact breaks it more. I believe not using curly braces is the correct way (this was also pointed out in a git issue).

What could be causing my .npmrc to not get the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

This technique does the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Setting up development env';

NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN=$(firebase functions:config:get npm.read_only)
NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN=$(eval echo $NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN)
rm -f ./.npmrc
echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN}" > .npmrc

# exit 0;
```